# A BrainF*ck-ish compiler in C

Tags: c, assembly, brainfuck, compiler

*-ish because I removed the input functionality from the compiler. And, the compiler does not support nested loops*

I've been recently reading up on compilers and how they work. Although this doesn't use most of the things I've learned about (the lexical and parser things), I thought it would be fun to try create a brainf*ck *compiler*, rather than an *interpreter*.

#### bfc.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int i;
static char *code; // these two as static so get_amt_to_change can easily interact

int get_amt_to_change(char c); // so the compiler doesn't write (ie) add di, 1 ten times

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    code = argv[1];
    puts("xor di, di\n"
         "setup_loop:\n"
         "mov byte [tape + di], 0\n"
         "add di, 1\n"
         "cmp di, 101\n"
         "jne setup_loop\n"
         "xor di, di"); // sets up the tape with all 0's
    int loop_count = 0; // to keep track of asm subroutines for [ and ]
    for(i = 0; code[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        switch(code[i]) {
            case '+':
                printf("add byte [tape + di], %d\n", get_amt_to_change('+'));
                break;
            case '-':
                printf("sub byte [tape + di], %d\n", get_amt_to_change('-'));
                break;
            case '>':
                printf("add di, %d\n", get_amt_to_change('>'));
                break;
            case '<':
                printf("sub di, %d\n", get_amt_to_change('<'));
                break;
            case '.':
                puts("mov ah, 0Eh\n"
                     "mov al, byte [tape +di]\n"
                     "int 10h");
                break;
            case '[':
                printf("cmp byte [tape + di], 0\n"
                       "je end_loop%d\n"
                       "start_loop%d:\n", loop_count, loop_count);
                break;
            case ']':
                printf("cmp byte [tape + di], 0\n"
                       "jne start_loop%d\n"
                       "end_loop%d:\n", loop_count, loop_count);
                loop_count++; // to not repeat subroutine names
                break;
        }
    }
    puts("jmp $\nsection .bss\ntape resb 100"); // a 100 byte tape
    return 0;
}

int get_amt_to_change(char c) {
    int amt;
    for(amt = 0; code[i] == c; amt++, i++);
    i--; // if it wasn't == c, then go back one character and find out what it was equal to in the next call
    return amt;
}
```

The above code reads Brainf*ck code passed via command line argument and produces an assembly code, which could then be passed into the NASM assembler.

## Examples

**Purpose**: <s>nothing. brainf*ck doesn't have a purpose</s> logs 'd' to output

#### Brainf*ck

**Note:** the backslashes are there so the terminal doesn't read the `<` and `>` symbols as it normally would.

```
\>++++++++++[\<++++++++++\>-]\<.
```

#### Assembly

```
xor di, di
setup_loop:
mov byte [tape + di], 0
add di, 1
cmp di, 101
jne setup_loop
xor di, di
add di, 1
add byte [tape + di], 10
cmp byte [tape + di], 0
je end_loop0
start_loop0:
sub di, 1
add byte [tape + di], 10
add di, 1
sub byte [tape + di], 1
cmp byte [tape + di], 0
jne start_loop0
end_loop0:
sub di, 1
mov ah, 0Eh
mov al, byte [tape +di]
int 10h
jmp $
section .bss
tape resb 100
```

---

**Purpose**: to show the generated assembly code for each of the symbols

#### Brainf*ck

```
++--\>\>\<\<.,[]
```

#### Assembly

```
xor di, di
setup_loop:
mov byte [tape + di], 0
add di, 1
cmp di, 101
jne setup_loop
xor di, di
add byte [tape + di], 2
sub byte [tape + di], 2
add di, 2
sub di, 2
mov ah, 0Eh
mov al, byte [tape +di]
int 10h
cmp byte [tape + di], 0
je end_loop0
start_loop0:
cmp byte [tape + di], 0
jne start_loop0
end_loop0:
jmp $
section .bss
tape resb 100
```

## Questions

- My C code only has one subroutine. Are there any other logical ones to add?
- I did a lot of optimizing on the assembly code output. Could it be further optimized?
- My main problem with compilers I've written in the past is that I've over-complicated things. Is that an issue with this (C) code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enlarge **tape** because your initialization zeroes 101 bytes.

```
 section .bss
 tape resb 101
```

When in graphics mode, the teletype function uses the BL and BH registers as arguments.

```
 mov  bx,0007h ;Display page 0 and Color 7
 mov  ah, 0Eh
 mov  al, byte [tape +di]
 int  10h
```

When in text mode, the teletype function uses the BH register as an argument.

```
 mov  bh,0     ;Display page 0
 mov  ah, 0Eh
 mov  al, byte [tape +di]
 int  10h
```

You can optimize the setup code by iterating backwards. It shaves off 2 instructions! It too will leave DI=0.

```
 mov  di, 101
setup_loop:
 sub di,1
 mov  byte [tape + di], 0
 jnz  setup_loop
```

I don't know if you would care but the code for **[ ]** by itself produces an infinite loop if the byte at [tape + di] is anything but zero.

Comment: I am a little confused by your second improvement recommendation. Since the BL and BH arguments are not required, why would I waste space by adding that instruction in? It seems pointless to me.

Comment: My BIOS reference includes them. You can also look it up in Ralph Brown Interrupt List. If you know for sure the display is not graphics then only code `mov bh,0`.

Comment: I, too, use that list but through my testing, I've discovered that those are not necessary (at least in text mode). I actually hadn't thought that the user might embed the code into another bit of code, which might be in a graphics mode at the point of entry. I recommend adding to your answer that the page number is necessary for graphics modes.